# Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

I am trying to use computed properties in another computed properties and when i run code i am getting following error in console.

**Cannot write a value to a `ko.computed` unless you specify a 'write' option**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this; 
    self.firstName = ko.observable('rahul');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('sharma');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.firstName() +' ' + self.lastName();
    });
    self.upperFullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.fullName.toUpperCase();
    });  
}
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

and here is html code and [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/PSajG/)

```
<p><input data-bind="value: firstName"></p>

<p><input data-bind="value: lastName"></p>

<p><input data-bind="value: fullName"></p>

<p> <span data-bind="text: upperFullName"> </span> </p>
```

Comment: why use a input when its not a writable computed?

Comment: @Anders sorry i didnt get you ? i am very much new in knockoutjs .

Comment: @Anders  OK got it , you want to say that when there is no calculation on upperFullName why should i use this as computed.Yes you are right . but how can i show then uppercase fullName  ?

Comment: No i meant that since you use a input and value binding to bind 'fullName' it indicates that you want to write to the observable, but you use a read only observable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

self.fullName is a function, returning the computed value.

```
self.upperFullName = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.fullName().toUpperCase();
});
```

notice the parenthesis!